# Search by multiple values using NEST(ElasticSearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an index called "**campaigns**" with these records:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "campaigns",
    "_id" : "cf08b05c-c8b5-45cb-bca8-17267c3613fb",
    "_source" : {
      "PublisherId" : 1,
      "CurrentStatus" : "Pending"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "campaigns",
    "_id" : "39436cb3-483e-4fb4-92e4-4e06ecad27a1",
    "_source" : {
      "PublisherId" : 1,
      "CurrentStatus" : "Approved"
    }
  }, 
{
    "_index" : "campaigns",
    "_id" : "21436cb1-583e-4fb4-92e4-4e06ecad23a2",
    "_source" : {
      "PublisherId" : 1,
      "CurrentStatus" : "Rejected"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to get all campaigns with "**PublisherId = 1**" and with any statuses between "**Approved,Rejected**". Something like this:

```
var statuses = new[] {CampaignStatus.Approved,CampaignStatus.Rejected};
campaigns.Where(c=> c.PublisherId == 1 && statuses.Contains(c.CurrentStatus)).ToList();
```

How can I run this query using NEST?

Expected Result:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "campaigns",
    "_id" : "39436cb3-483e-4fb4-92e4-4e06ecad27a1",
    "_source" : {
      "PublisherId" : 1,
      "CurrentStatus" : "Approved"
    }
  }, 
{
    "_index" : "campaigns",
    "_id" : "39436cb3-483e-4fb4-92e4-4e06ecad27a1",
    "_source" : {
      "PublisherId" : 1,
      "CurrentStatus" : "Rejected"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the syntax of `nest` but as ES is REST based , providing working example query in JSON format, which you can convert to `nest` code.

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "PublisherId": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "CurrentStatus": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index all three sample docs and use below search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "PublisherId": 1
                }
            },
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "CurrentStatus": "Rejected"
                    }
                },
                {
                     "match": {
                        "CurrentStatus": "Approved"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "stof_63968525",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.9808291,
                "_source": {
                    "PublisherId": 1,
                    "CurrentStatus": "Approved"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "stof_63968525",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1.9808291,
                "_source": {
                    "PublisherId": 1,
                    "CurrentStatus": "Rejected"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Please note the use of `minimum_should_match` which forces atleast one of status `Rejected` and `Approved` to match and refer [bool query in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to understand the query construct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
            QueryContainer queryAnd = new TermQuery() { Field = "PublisherId", Value = 1 };
            QueryContainer queryOr = new TermQuery() { Field = "CurrentStatus", Value = "Approved" };
                           queryOr |= new TermQuery() { Field = "CurrentStatus", Value = "Rejected" };
            QueryContainer queryMain = queryAnd & queryOr;

            ISearchResponse<campaigns> searchReponse = elasticClient.Search<campaigns>(s => s
                .Query(q2 => q2
                            .Bool(b => b
                            .Should(queryMain)
                        )));
```