# Matching multiple phrases to one field in Elastic Search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have built an application in C# which searches my Elasticsearch documents and this all works fine using this code....

```
List<AuditLog> resultsList = Client.SearchAsync<AuditLog>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Take(noRows)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(mu => mu.MatchPhrase(mp => mp.Field("audit_Event").Query(auditEvents)),
                mu => mu.Match(ma => ma.Field(field).Query(value))
             )
          )
     )).Result.Documents.ToList();
```

This all works fine but there is a new requirement to search the audit_Event field against multiple phrases, such as "User Login", "Add Employee" etc

I have found reference to multi_match but this appears to be more related to searching across multiple fields rather than multiple values in one field.

Following discussions below, TermQuery would seem to do the job but doesn't return any values. Any ideas?

```
QueryContainer queryAnd = new TermQuery() { Field = "audit_Application", Value = "MyApplication" };
QueryContainer queryOr = new TermQuery() { Field = "audit_Event", Value = "Employee Inserted" };
queryOr |= new TermQuery() { Field = "audit_Event", Value = "Employee Updated" }; 
QueryContainer queryMain = queryAnd & queryOr;

resultsList = Client.SearchAsync<AuditLog>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Take(noRows)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(queryMain)
        )
    )).Result.Documents.ToList();
```

I've also checked the two queries using Kibana, the first one returns data but the second one doesn't, and am now wondering if it a problem with how the data is indexed....

```
GET auditlog/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "audit_Event": "Employee Updated"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "audit_Event": "Employee Inserted"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

GET auditlog/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "terms": {
        "audit_Event": ["Employee Updated","Employee Inserted"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63972341/1068246

Comment: Looked in to this and this would work as it allows me to build the queries up programatically depending on what the user selects but unfortunately it doesn't return any values. Have amended the main question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your statement that the `OR` query works as expected, below is a way you can build the query using `NEST`. You may make any specific modifications as needed.

This snippet of code is responsible for triggering the search call

```
var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<AuditLog>()
    .Query(q => Blah(auditEventsList))
    .From(0)
    .Take(noRows);
    // other methods you want to chain here

var response = Client.searchAsync<AuditLog>(searchDescriptor);
```

The search query is generated here. Notice the use of `SHOULD` and the call to another method that is responsible for dynamically generating the `match_phrase` queries.

```
private static QueryContainer Blah(List<string> auditEventsList)
{
    return new QueryContainerDescriptor<AuditLog>().Bool(
        b => b.Should(
            InnerBlah(auditEventsList)
        )
    );
}
```

This method generates an array of `match_phrase` queries that are passed to `should` in the above snippet. These are generated by iterating over all the audit events that are received.

```
private static QueryContainer[] InnerBlah(List<string> auditEventsList)
{
    QueryContainer orQuery = null;
    List<QueryContainer> queryContainerList = new List<QueryContainer>();
    foreach(var item in auditEventsList)
    {
        orQuery = new MatchPhraseQuery { Field = "audit_Event", Query = item };
        queryContainerList.Add(orQuery);
    }
    return queryContainerList.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to match multiple phrases against a single field, then you can use the following combinations of [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with match_phrase**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "audit_Event": "User Login"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "audit_Event": "Add Employee"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @adig14 did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: This works in Kibana but need to be able to programatically build the query up depending on what the user selects.

Comment: @adig14 I am not familiar with c# :|, but if my answer helped you in any way then please don't forget to upvote my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, you answer gave me a way of testing in Kibana but the "must" has to be a "should" otherwise the condition can not be met.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
QueryContainer queryOr = new MatchPhraseQuery() { Field = "audit_Event", Query = "Employee Inserted" };
        queryOr |= new MatchPhraseQuery() { Field = "audit_Event", Query = "Employee Updated" };
        ISearchResponse<AuditLog> resultAuditLog = Client.Search<AuditLog>(s => s
                    .RequestConfiguration(r => r.DisableDirectStreaming())
                    .From(0)
                    .Size(100)
                    .Query(q2 => q2
                        .Bool(b => b
                        .Should(queryOr))
                    )
        );
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. Could it be how the data is stored in elasticsearch? In Kibana doing..

GET auditlog/_search
{
"query" : {
    "match": {
          "audit_Event": "Employee Inserted"
        }
      }
  }

Returns data but doing....

GET auditlog/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "terms": {
        "audit_Event": ["Employee Inserted"]
    }
  }
}

Doesn't.

Comment: `audit_Event` field contains the same words that we searched? If not you should use `WildcardQuery` with`*Employee Updated*` I've edited the answer.

Comment: Should be an exact match of the phrases "Employee Inserted" or "Employee Updated"

Comment: Is there any analyzer on that field?

Comment: Not specifically added one so would only be the default one. Looking on Google it mentions about using "Indexes" with "Terms". Should I be creating an index with all my "event_Audit" values in it so that they can be found by the Terms?